# Convert from string "yyyyMMdd" to Calendar in java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I need to use Calendar class. This is my code, but it has an error certainly. How can I fix it?

```
String stringdate = "20161129";
String pattern = "yyyyMMdd";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(stringdate);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Comment: What's the error?  What do you expect?

Comment: i dont get any errors there

Comment: @duffymo: sorry, I have fixed already. But is that the correct parsing way ? I have never worked with Java before.

Comment: So what are you asking?   Run the code. Does it work according to your requirements and expectations?  If yes, then it's fine.  I'd recommend that you use JDK 8 and the new time package.  Calendar is Java 1.0 vintage.

Comment: @amateur **Search Stack Overflow** before posting. This topic is addressed hundreds of times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good...

2 things can happen her:

1. you are not using the correct DAte class (`import java.util.Date;`)
2. you are not considering (catching or rethrowing ) the **ParseException**

in both cases you will get a compilation error...

like type mismatch

[image]

or unhandled exception

[image]